# cannot get result post id after sharing a URL to facebook by ios app (swift)

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I'm writing an iOS app to do URL sharing.

Using technology Swift.

I found that sharing by FBSDKShareContent() CANNOT get back any post id from result object in FBSDKSharingDelegate inside method didCompleteWithResults. 
Result object contains empty row:
sharer didCompleteWithResults, results.count0

```
[:]
```

plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated

this is my code

1. fb share button part

   ```
   func showLinkButton()

       {
           var addURL =  "http://tw.yahoo.com"

           let content : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
           content.contentURL = NSURL(string:addURL)

           var dialog: FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
           dialog.fromViewController = self
           dialog.shareContent = content

           dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.ShareSheet
           //dialog.delegate = self
           dialog.show()

       }
   ```

---

2.FBSDKSharingDelegate part

```
  func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didCompleteWithResults results: [NSObject: AnyObject])
{
    println("sharer didCompleteWithResults, results.count\(results.count)")
    println(results)

}

func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("sharer NSError")
    println(error.description)
}


func sharerDidCancel(sharer: FBSDKSharing!)
{
    println("sharerDidCancel")
}
```

what's wrong with my code? or any problems?
thanks a lot!

Comment: Any solution you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, the `post_id` is only returned if the user is logged into your Facebook app and has granted the `publish_actions` permission.

If these conditions are not met, the id shouldn't be returned.

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let photo = FBSDKSharePhoto()
photo.image = chosenImage
photo.isUserGenerated = false
let photoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
photoContent.photos = [photo]
let shareApiInstance = FBSDKShareAPI()
shareApiInstance.message = "customized facebook content"
shareApiInstance.shareContent = photoContent
shareApiInstance.delegate = self
shareApiInstance.share()
```

// Delegate Methods

```
func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
    print("delegates called")
    let resultsInfo = results as! [String : Any]
    print(resultsInfo["postId"] as! String)
}

func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
    print("sharer NSError")
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}


func sharerDidCancel(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!) {
    print("sharerDidCancel")
}
```

with the above workaround, you can access posted.
if you have publish_actions permissions then only it will be possible